# Measuring multi line textview with height set to wrap_content not working

Tags: android, textview

The problem is, that a `TextView` (I marked it in the layout code) is cutting off it's text in the sense of that it only shows 1 of 2 lines and I don't see why this is happening...

I tried using following in the `TextView`(as I found that in other threads):

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

and

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

But this does not help anything...

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/main_background_color"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFolderStyle"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/action_folder_style"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:src="?ic_color_lens_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/action_folder_style"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <!-- The following text view has two lines 
                 but is measured as if it only has one! -->

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/action_folder_style_info"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```